# How do I make sure customers don't skip paywall with stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am building a marketplace with a model similar to fiverr. You pay for a service, and after you pay you can fill out the preferences that you want from the seller. The problem I am facing is that the successlink after payment can be just copy and pasted to progress to the preferences page without payment. How do I ensure this doesn't happen with stripe. Here is my server code:

```
//checkout stripe session code:
 app.post('/create-checkout-session', async (req, res) => {
 const {request} = req;
 const account_id = req.body.account_id;
 const user_id = req.body.user_id;
 var successLink = 'http://localhost:3000/dashboard/userreq/'+user_id;
 console.log('request: ' + req.body.account_id);
 const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [
    {
    price_data: {
      currency: 'usd',
      product_data: {
        name: 'Story',
      },
      unit_amount: 1300,
    },
    quantity: 1,
  },
],
payment_intent_data: {
application_fee_amount: 123,
transfer_data: {
  destination: account_id,
 },
},
mode: 'payment',
success_url: successLink,
cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/cancel.html',
});
 res.send({
sessionId: session.id,
 });});
```

```
//webhook to see if payment was successful
app.post('/webhook', bodyParser.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  const sig = request.headers['stripe-signature'];

  let event;

  // Verify webhook signature and extract the event.
  // See https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures for more information.
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    return response.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  if (event.type === 'checkout.session.completed') {
    const session = event.data.object;
    handleCompletedCheckoutSession(session);
  }

  response.json({received: true});
});

const handleCompletedCheckoutSession = (session) => {
  // Fulfill the purchase.
  console.log(JSON.stringify(session));
}

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => {
  console.log("Server started...");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd want to encode the Checkout Session ID within your success URL: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-success-page#modify-success-url

Then when your success page is hit, you'd check to see if the session ID is valid by retrieving the Checkout Session from the backend and checking its `payment_status`: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-payment_status

If there's no session ID or the `payment_status` is not `paid`, then you wouldn't grant access to whatever it is that you're selling.